# Scripting (PyQGIS) the match to symbols from file (XML) in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, style

In QGIS (2.1x) > layer properties > having symbology by categories and symbols classes configured in a XML file (external source) - being "ID_UCF" the key field for the classification - is it possible to automate the operation/option of **match to symbols from file**? We are investigating around PyQt to try a solution... Any help?

[image]